# Append an element to be a parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I was wondering was it possible to append an element using jquery to be a parent.

Imagine I had this on my page:

```
<div id="inner">

</div>
```

And I wanted to put #inner inside another div #outer with jquery after some kind of event.

The result would be:

```
<div id="outer"> - This element was appended with JQUERY
   <div id="inner">
   </div>
</div>
```

Not sure that this is possible. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sure it's possible. In the DOM  you have nodes that can be easily repositioned. Might be a good idea to read a basic tutorial on DOM programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrap function should do the trick :)

```
var mkup = '<div id="outer"></div>';
$('#inner').wrap('<div id="outer"></div');
```

Comment: This is the post I read first. Every other post gets a vote up. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

see this http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
$('#inner').wrap('<div id="outer"></div>')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#inner').wrap('<div id="outer"></div');
```

should do it.

Answer (score 2):

what you need is the **[wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)** function:

```
$('#inner').wrap('<div id="outer"></div>');
$('#inner').before(' - this element was appended with jQuery');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible in jQuery.

Please have a look on the jQuery API -> .wrap():
http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
$("#inner").wrap('<div id="outer" style="background-color: #ddd"></div>');
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/QL79C/1/

Hope this helps!